# Keras Lambda Layer & Theano Code: Accessing dimensions and values of TensorVariable

Tags: eval, keras, theano

First, I'm very new to Keras and Theano. I'm implementing a CNN which uses local response normalization(LRN). As far as i know there's no such layer implemented in the basic functionality of both keras and theano. So i tried using a keras lambda layer to implement LRN.

'def local_response_normalization(x):
    #LRN parameters
    k = 2
    n = 5
    alpha = 0.0001
    beta = 0.75

```
result = x.eval()
x_tmp = x.eval()


#building functions for the theano computation graph
scalar_op = T.dscalar('scalar_op')
matrix1_op = T.dmatrix('matrix1_op')
matrix2_op = T.dmatrix('matrix2_op')
mul_result = scalar_op * matrix1_op
add_result = scalar_op + matrix1_op
pow_result = matrix1_op ** scalar_op
div_result = matrix1_op / matrix2_op

sc_mat_mul_f = function([scalar_op, matrix1_op], mul_result)
sc_mat_add_f = function([scalar_op, matrix1_op], add_result)
sc_mat_pow_f = function([scalar_op, matrix1_op], pow_result)
mat_div_f = function([matrix1_op, matrix2_op], div_result)

#x is supposed to be a 3-dimensional tensor (a x b x c)
a_dim = x_tmp.shape[0]
b_dim = x_tmp.shape[1]
c_dim = x_tmp.shape[2]

#iterating through channels
for i in range(0, a_dim):
    j_l = max(0, i-(n/2))# j_l(ower_bound)
    j_u = min(N-1, i+(n/2))# j_u(pper_bound)

    x_tmp = x.eval()
    #retrieving set of local 'neurons' 
    x_tmp = x_tmp[j_l:j_u+1,:,:]
    #building squared sum
    x_tmp = T.sqr(x_tmp)#TensorVariable
    x_tmp = T.sum(x_tmp, axis=0)#axis no. 0 = 'channel' axis
    #x_tmp is now 2-dimensional
    x_tmp = sc_mat_mul_f(alpha, x_tmp.eval())
    x_tmp = sc_mat_add_f(k, x_tmp)
    x_tmp = sc_mat_pow_f(beta, x_tmp)
    x_tmp = mat_div_f(result[i], x_tmp)
    #exchanging channel i with x_tmp ( = LRN )
    result[i] = x_tmp

return result`
```

I'm integrating this layer into the model by using `model.add(local_response_normalization, ...)`
When trying to compile and fit the model i get:

`theano.gof.fg.MissingInputError: Input 0 of the graph (indices start from 0), used to compute AbstractConv2d{convdim=2, border_mode='half', subsample=(4, 4), filter_flip=True, imshp=(None, 3, 220, 220), kshp=(96, 3, 11, 11), filter_dilation=(1, 1)}(/conv2d_1_input, InplaceDimShuffle{3,2,0,1}.0), was not provided and not given a value. Use the Theano flag exception_verbosity='high', for more information on this error.`

The main issue seems to be that eval() cannot be called during compilation of a model. I can't find another way to access and operate on elements of x (being an output tensor of a conv2d layer) other than converting it into a numpy array by using eval(), but that clearly doesn't work. It seems to me that i'm missing a main concept behind Lambda Layers and TensorVariables in general.
I spent the last two days dealing with this problem and i'm really stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out a way to do all computations for LRN without evaluating TensorVariables. Which was kind of obvious.